# Why can't I connect to SSH server from Ubuntu client? (while windows client is okay)

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, client

I have configured an ssh server on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine. I changed the listening port to the one different from the default port 22 (that's the only change I made on the server).

I am trying to connect to the server from a Ubuntu remote machine but the connection is refused. The weird thing is that I can connect to the server from a Windows remote machine.

What makes this difference? How can I make the Ubuntu remote machine get connected to the server?

[Server]

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04.03 64bit Desktop
- Checked the ssh process is running
- Firewall: not changed from default status
- Checked the ssh port is open to public

[Ubuntu Remote Machine]

- OS: Ubuntu 13.04 or 13.10 64bit Desktop
- Client Software: Vinagre
- Firewall: not changed from default status

[Windows Remote Machine]

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit
- Client Software: Tera Term
- Firewall: not changed from default status

Comment: Try `ssh user@hostname_or_IPaddress:alternate_port_number`

Answer (score 3):

When Connect to Ubuntu Server from Linux Client Via Terminal, Specify the port Number,
 Suppose that your server ip 192.168.16.10 (any hostname) ,with port 39

at terminal

```
ssh username@192.168.16.10 -p 39
```

where username is exist username on that server you connect , -p : specify the port number.

At Vinagre Client , New Connection , then Specify the hostname:portnumber, [image]

Answer (score 0):

If "connection refused" is exactly what you are getting, that means the TCP port you are trying to reach doesn't have any service listening on it.  Maybe you are using a bad ssh command parameter, and the test is trying to reach original ssh port. You could listen multiple ports the same time, adding lines with the "Port" variable to "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" file. You could use "Port 22" and "Port 139", and check if test is trying to use port 22.